# How to draw multiple rectangles (according to coordinates) over a shapfile in R?

Tags: r, raster, shapefile

I would like to plot multiple rectangles over an area to show the subregions.

The subregions are divided into the following:

1) Northwest Himalaya and Karakoram (HKH1; 71°‒79°E, 32°‒39°N), 
2) central Himalaya (HKH2; 76°‒93°E, 27°‒32°N) 
3)Southeast Himalaya and Tibetan Plateau
(HKH3; 93°‒103°E, 28°‒36°N)

The three rectangles are shown here
[image]

I have tried many codes but failed to reach what I desire.
Any kind of help will be truly appreciated!

Comment: Next time, please show some R code to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

As these are rectangles, you can do

```
library(raster)
HKH1 <- as(extent(71, 79, 32, 39), "SpatialPolygons")
HKH2 <- as(extent(76, 93, 27, 32), "SpatialPolygons") 
HKH3 <- as(extent(93, 103, 28, 36), "SpatialPolygons")
p <- bind(HKH1, HKH2, HKH3)
```

Or, perhaps better if you had many rectangles

```
m <- matrix(c(71, 79, 32, 39, 76, 93, 27, 32, 93, 103, 28, 36), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
a <- apply(m, 1, function(i) as(extent(i), "SpatialPolygons"))
pp <- bind(a)
```

For more complex polygons, see `?raster::spPolygons`